# jquery,cfc login/forgot password check for existing record in database

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I've been trying to make something similar to the login/forgot password popups on download.cnet.com. While my code actually works fine, there is a catch. I cannot make it work on enter. The form is submitted, but the ajax call is skipped.

In this regard, I removed the submit button and used a `div` instead. Then on click:

```
$('#loginButton').click(function(){
  // ajax call check for existing record via cfc 
  // and returns true or false after which the appropriate 
  // actions are taken depending on returned value. 
  }
)};
```

Everything works fine, but I've been wondering how the cnet guys made it work on enter. If you check their website you'll see what I am talking about.

Comment: Can't you just call your function onSubmit in the form tag too as a backup?

Comment: I tried to replace click with submit within jcript but it does not work. do you suggest here to double the code?

Comment: You create a function that the jQuery .click function calls and in the <form onSubmit="theSameFunction()"> tag.

Comment: nope, I've already tried that and it did not work. onsubmit popup window closes and ajax is skipped

Answer (score 0):

If your referring to cnets's login with cnet, and lost password feature, it looks like they are popping up a window, and loading that form's content with an iframe.

I guess in theory, if you load a colorbox with an iframe, and submit within the iframe and display that info there, the color box should stay open until closed.

Answer (score 0):

You say the onsubmit popup window closes.  That must mean that your function actually starts.

I suggest exploring your function to see why the call to your cfc is being skipped, it in fact it is.  Also, once you figure it out, put the submit button back.  Changing the default behaviour of an html form simply annoys people who know how to use a keyboard.

One other thing.  If you are using cfform, you may have to send the form to the js function.  In other words, instead of this:

```
<cfform onsubmit="yourFunction()">
```

do this

```
<cfform onsubmit="yourFunction(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking "enter" submits the form so you'll want to also call it onSubmit. It sounds like your function is working (but you didn't post your code, so it's anyone's guess... shame on you)  but the page submit isn't allowing you to see anything that is happening.  If you want to stop the form from submitting you need to return false `onsubmit = "return yourFunction()"`.  when your function returns false it will prevent the form from submitting.

see [JavaScript Form Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp)